# Textbox Text was truncated in jquery if contains any space

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to update text to textbox but it ignore text after whitespace

```
$.each(areas, function(i, value) {
    $("#Area_block_edit").append("<div class='textBoxStyles1'>" +
        "<article class='passwordBodyText'>Name</article>" +
        "<input type='text' readonly='true' class='newregionText' value=" + value + " /></div>");
});

<section class='forgetPasswordSection' id='AddNewMultipleRegionSectionId'>
    <div class='closeBtn' id='closeBtnId'>&times;</div>
    <article class='headerText pswHeaderText'>Edit Multiple Area</article>
    <div class='hrClass'></div>
    <div class='scrollBarClass' id="Area_block_edit"></div>
    <div class='hrefLinks'>
        <a class='hrefClick' href='#' title="+ Add More" id="addmoreArea">+ Add More</a>
        <input type="button" value="Save Area" title="SaveArea" class='AreaBtn okBtn' id='AddNewAreas' />
    </div>
</section>
```

i'm updating like above  . . areas contain following texts testing 123 , testing 1234 but it added only testing , testing in textbox

Comment: what do you mean with "text after whitespace"? which whitespace?

Comment: yes text after white space shared my HTML also